# Need to generate random set of words from five different column, A word should be included from every column

Tags: php

```
$array['v1'] = array('tt','yyy');
$array['v2'] = array('xx','ccc');
$array['v3'] = array('gg','ggg');
$array['v4'] = array('nnn','nnn');
$array['v5'] = array('mmm','ooo');
```

need to generate random set like below by including value from all column

```
tt-xx-gg-nnn-ooo
tt-xx-gg-nnn-mmm
tt-xx-ggg-nnn-mmm .... up to possible pair
```

Comment: We're not a code writing service! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried with array_rand function but it's looping too much, That's why I have posted here for better option

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Show us what you've tried, expected result and what currently happens.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far and error or specific issue you are facing.

Comment: This is known as a _cartesian join_, _cartesian product_, or a _cross join_ — depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$attributeValues = array(
    'v1' => array('tt', 'yyy'),
    'v2' => array('xx','ccc'),
    'v3' => array('gg','ggg'),
    'v4' => array('nnn','nnn'),
    'v5' => array('mmm','ooo')
);

class Cartesian
{
    public static function build($set)
    {
        if (!$set) {
            return array(array());
        }

        $subset = array_shift($set);
        $cartesianSubset = self::build($set);

        $result = array();
        foreach ($subset as $value) {
            foreach ($cartesianSubset as $p) {
                array_unshift($p, $value);
                $result[] = $p;
            }
        }

        return $result;        
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r(Cartesian::build($attributeValues));
// loop and implode
```

This code solved my requirement. Thanks @LachlanMcD for the clue